# Return type of function that returns a document (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

I have a function on my project that executes a query that returns a document of a model using mongoose:

Box model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Types } from 'mongoose';

export interface Box {
  name: string
  set: Types.ObjectId
}

const BoxSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true, dropDups: true },
    set: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Set', required: true }
});

const Box = mongoose.model<Box>('Box', BoxSchema);
export default Box;
```

Box controller:

```
import Box from '../models/Box';

static async getAllBoxes () {
  return await Box.find({}).exec();
}
```

Since I'm converting my code to TypeScript, I have to define the return type of my function. My IDE suggested me I do it like so:

```
import Box from '../models/Box';

static async getAllBoxes (): Promise<(Document<unknown, any, Box> & Box & { id: Types.ObjectId; })[]> {
  return await Box.find({}).exec();
}
```

However, that throws me the following error:

```
'Box' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Box'?
```

I tried by placing `typeof Box`, just as suggested, but that throws me this error on the `await return`.

```
Type '(Document<unknown, any, Box> & Box & { _id: ObjectId; })[]' is not assignable to type '(Document<unknown, any, Model<Box, {}, {}, {}, any>> & Model<Box, {}, {}, {}, any> & { id: ObjectId; })[]'.
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What is `Box`? You never showed us what is in that file.

Comment: _"that throws me an error as well"_... which is?

Comment: I'd be surprised if you actually need to specify the return type. Can it not be inferred from `Box.find({}).exec()`?

Comment: @caTS It's the DB model

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (it's too general). You need to show us what is in the file so we know for sure what the type of `Box` is. Also, a minimal reproducible example would be greatly beneficial.

Comment: I edited my question to include the remaining code

Comment: Have you tried just leaving it as your original JS code (just rename the file to `.ts`)? Again, I'd be very surprised if Typescript actually complains about it

Comment: @Phil My code runs fine, however, ESLint complains about it

Comment: So what does ESLint have to say?

Comment: @Phil If I left my original code, it says `Missing return type on function`

Comment: What is your ESLint configuration? It works just fine for me with absolutely no complaints